# Rails 4: Model.joins(...) not selecting empty relationships

Tags: sql, join, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have Partner model which belongs to a PartnerType, which inherits from a polymorphic Lookup model.

On my #index page, I'm trying to list all the partners and also display their associated partner_type if they have one.  Trying to optimize this into 1 query, I joined on the partner_type (via the lookups table) but it seems that this query ONLY returns partners that have a related partner_type.  I'm sure this is the expected behavior, but I'm not very knowledgeable about the under-workings of the join.

```
# partners_controller.rb
def index
    # Only grabs partners WITH an associated partner_type
    @partners = Partner.joins(:partner_type).select("partners.*, lookups.value as partner_type_value")
  end
```

How can I create 1 query that selects ALL partners AND the related partner_type, if they have one?

**Edit**

```
@partners = Partner.includes(:partner_type).select("partners.*, lookups.value as partner_type_vale").references(:partner_type)
```

This works, but I don't know if it's the 'best' solution.

Answer (score 0):

`@partners = Partner.includes(:partner_type).select("partners.*, lookups.value as partner_type_vale").references(:partner_type)`

is indeed the solution for this problem. It loads the relationship if it exists but also returns parent objects that don't have any child relationship.

Situation would be:

`parent has_many children` and 
`child belongs_to parent`

and you want to return ALL parents and their children, EVEN those parents without any children.

```
parent(a) has child(john)
parent(b) has no children
```

`Parent.includes(:children).references(:children)` would return BOTH parent A and B, even though only A has associated children.